# Chart.JS - stacked bar chart

Tags: vue.js, frontend, coldfusion, chart.js

[image]

I have successfully created a Stacked bar chart in Chart.js, the only issue is there are tags(with the specific amount of counts/numbers that each portion of the stacked bar has. Does anyone know the path within Chart.js to Remove this?

I have read the documentation and looked on other sites but cannot find any answers as to what these numbers may be called

```
DefaultBar:{

    Type: 'bar',
    data:{
        datasets:[],
        labels:[]
    },
    options:{
        responsive:true,
        plugins:{
            title:{
                display:true,
                text: 'Discontinue Reasons',
                font:{
                    size: 20,
                    weight: 'bold'
                }
            },
            subtitle:{
                display:true,
                text: 'Additional Subtitles'
            },
            legend:{
                display: true,
                position: 'right'
            },
            tooltip:{
                enabled: true
            }
        },
        scales: {

            y:{
                title:{
                    display:true, 
                    text: 'Count',
                    font:{
                        size: 18
                    }
                },
                stacked:true,
                border:{
                    width: 2,
                }
            },
            x:{
                stacked: true,
                title:{
                    display:true,
                    text: 'Year',
                    font:{
                        size: 18
                    }
                },
                border:{
                    width:2,
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The best way to remove them is to not put them there in the first place.  Please post the code you used to create the chart and one of us will spot the offending attribute.

Comment: Just added that code snippet for ya

Comment: Those are called "data labels". They are not produced by any of the code you show. As @DanBracuk remarked, they are not a normal occurrence on chart.js charts, you have to use some extra code (like a plugin) to make them appear. Look at [all samples](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/stacked.html) on chart.js site - you will not find them. You will however find them on [chartjs-datalabels plugin samples](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/samples/charts/bar.html) but your code does not show that  plugin or any other code that would produce data labels.

Comment: @GabrielWilkins your code snippet is not complete. It doesn't create anything. There is no data in it, also the calling constructor methods are missing, Also, from seeing your output, there should be a chartjs-plugin-datalabels somewhere in your code (see https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/samples/charts/bar.html). When asking questions please give a complete working example of what is causing your issue. The code you added doesn't do anything you've said.